# apache camel use simple to read and print out file content does not work

Tags: apache-camel

I want to use simple to read and print out file content. but it reads file and only print out file name instead of content.

Why? Did I did something wrong?

```
from(SOAP_ENDPOINT + "&dataFormat=CXF_MESSAGE")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "#####  SOAP REQUEST  ##### ${body}")
.to("language:simple:wsdl/dummyResponse.xml").convertBodyTo(String.class)
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "#####  SOAP RESPONSE  ##### ${body}");
```

Any suggestion and ideas are more than welcome!

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [Camel docs](http://camel.apache.org/language.html) the pattern you use executes a script in the declared language.

```
language:simple:wsdl/dummyResponse.xml
```

means: execute the script "wsdl/dummyResponse.xml" that contains Simple expressions. I assume that the filename is the result of trying to execute the XML (some fallback result perhaps).

To read the `dummyResponse` from filesystem you can for example use a [Java bean](http://camel.apache.org/bean.html) or the [Content enricher EIP](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html)